# How to replace part of the data-frame with another data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have two data frames and i like to filter the data and replace list of columns from df1 with the same columns in df2

i want to filter this df by `df1.loc[df1["name"]=="A"]`

```
first_data={"col1":[2,3,4,5,7],
"col2":[4,2,4,6,4],
"col3":[7,6,9,11,2],
"col4":[14,11,22,8,5],
"name":["A","A","V","A","B"],
"n_roll":[8,2,1,3,9]}
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(first_data)
```

and put the columns ["col1","col2","n_roll"] when name="A"
on the same places in df2 (on the same indexs)

```
sec_df={"col1":[55,0,57,1,3],
"col2":[55,0,4,4,53],
"col3":[55,33,9,0,2],
"col4":[55,0,22,4,5],
"name":["A","A","V","A","B"],
"n_roll":[8,2,1,3,9]}
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sec_df)
```

if i put that list of cols=[col1,col2,col3,col4]

so i like to get this

```
data={"col1":[55,0,4,1,7],
"col2":[55,0,4,4,4],
"col3":[55,33,9,0,2],
"col4":[55,0,22,4,5],
"name":["A","A","V","A","B"],
"n_roll":[8,2,1,3,9]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can achieve this with a double `combine_first`
2. Combine a filtered version of df1 with df2
3. However, the columns that were excluded in the filtered version of df1 were left behind and you have `NaN` values. But, that is okay -- Just do another `combine_first` on `df2` to get those values!

---

```
(df1.loc[df1['name'] != 'A', ["col1","col2","n_roll"]]
 .combine_first(df2)
 .combine_first(df2))
Out[1]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4  n_roll name
0  55.0  55.0  55.0  55.0     8.0    A
1   0.0   0.0  33.0   0.0     2.0    A
2   4.0   4.0   9.0  22.0     1.0    V
3   1.0   4.0   0.0   4.0     3.0    A
4   7.0   4.0   2.0   5.0     9.0    B
```

Comment: if my cols was cols= =[col1,col2,col3,col4]

so i want to get this:

'data={"col1":[55,0,4,1,7],
"col2":[55,0,4,4,4],
"col3":[55,33,9,0,2],
"col4":[55,0,22,4,5],
"name":["A","A","V","A","B"],
"n_roll":[8,2,1,3,9]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df'

Comment: @matan can you kindly post expected output in your question so that it is nicely formatted?

Comment: thank you, btw is was my bad .
the hight  is n_roll in the Original data.
i just edit that

Comment: The solution needs to change to  [df1['name'] == 'A'
and its works! thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use one line to achieve this man!

```
df1=df1[df1.name!='A'].append(df2[df2.name=='A'].rename(columns={'hight':'n_roll'})).sort_index()



   col1  col2  col3  col4 name  n_roll
0    55    55    55    55    A       8
1     0     0    33     0    A       2
2     4     4     9    22    V       1
3     1     4     0     4    A       3
4     7     4     2     5    B       9
```

**How it works**

```
d=df1[df1.name!='A']#selects df1 where name is not A

df2[df2.name=='A']#selects df where name is A

e=df2[df2.name=='A'].rename(columns={'hight':'n_roll'})#renames column height to allow appending

d.append(e)# combines the dataframes

d.append(e).sort_index()#sorts the index
```

Comment: You're in the right direction, but you did not address the requirement of specific columns.
And there was a mistake  on the data that correct. Now there is no need to rename

Comment: What issues on the columns?

Comment: i want to replace only the cols=["col1","col2","n_roll"]